# How to pass credentials in defaultProxy config setting?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sharepoint, proxy

A client is unable to use my webpart because he is behind a proxy server and they need to specify a username and password to get past the proxy.  I have this in my config file right now:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>        
      <proxy usesystemdefault="False" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" bypassonlocal="True"   />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Is there a way to supply a username and password to this proxy setting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do this in defaultProxy section of web.config, but you can definitely do it from code. Try this:

```
// Get proxy server info from AppSettings section of Web.Config
var proxyServerAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ "proxyServerAddress" ];
var proxyServerPort = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ "proxyServerPort" ];

// Get proxy with default credentials 
WebProxy proxy =new WebProxy(proxyServerAddress, proxyServerPort);
proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials();
```

Web.Config (configuration section):

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="proxyServerAddress" value="proxy.myhost.com" />
  <add key="proxyServerPort" value="8080" />
</appSettings>
```

And then assign `proxy` to the webClient you are using in your webPart.

**EDIT:**

If I had done more homework, I would have realized your problem could have been fixed with one attribute: useDefaultCredentials="true"

```
<system.net>  
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"> 
        <proxy usesystemdefault="False" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" bypassonlocal="True" />  
    </defaultProxy>  
</system.net>
```

Comment: Thanks.  But this would need to be the credentials of my client...not really sure I can get his password.  Anyway I can get around this?

Comment: You think I can set up the address and port in the config and just add the proxy.Credentials line in the code?

Comment: Thanks! Is this not the same as doing this:

<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">   
      <proxy usesystemdefault="False" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" bypassonlocal="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>

Comment: You're absolutely right. I wish I had thought of that before I went through all the "wheel-reinventing".

Comment: Thanks!  What's the usesystemdefault=false for and why is it false?

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Where do we define the credentials? What if the logged in user's credentials do not match the needed credentials on the proxy server?