# Can I extend all HttpWebRequest instances in my project?

Tags: c#, .net, httprequest

I use in my project many times the `HttpWebRequest`:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestedData) as HttpWebRequest;
```

Now, server's admin set a proxy for my connections. I'd like to add at any instance a code like this:

```
IWebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(Proxy, ProxyPort);
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential();

nc.UserName = ProxyLogin;
nc.Password = ProxyPassword;
request.Proxy = proxy;
request.Proxy.Credentials = nc;
```

without search for `request` on my project and add this code (as function).

Is there a fast way?

Comment: `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy`?

Comment: ? I'm using `HttpWebRequest`....

Comment: But you said that you were using `WebRequest.Create(requestedData)` to *create* those `HttpWebRequest` objects, and `WebRequest` has a static property called `DefaultWebProxy`.

Comment: Yes, but if So I need to replace all my connections with all code! I've Just asked if I can extend it in some way...

Comment: You seem to be trying to make more work for yourself than you need. I'm saying you create one instance of the proxy object, assign it to `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy`, and after that time, every call to `WebRequest.Create()` will already have that proxy assigned. There's no need to run code separately for each instance created.

Comment: Can you give to me an example? I don't understand what do you mean...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During startup (e.g. at the start of `Main` for a console project, inside Global.asax's `Application_Start` for a web project, run the following code:

```
IWebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(Proxy, ProxyPort);
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential();

nc.UserName = ProxyLogin;
nc.Password = ProxyPassword;
proxy.Credentials = nc;
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;
```

After that above code has run, **any** code that looks like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestedData) as HttpWebRequest;
```

Will find that the `Proxy` property is already set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the proxy for all HTTP requests from your application in the configuration with the [`<defaultProxy>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy
        usesystemdefaults="true"
        proxyaddress="http://192.168.1.10:3128"
        bypassonlocal="true"
      />
      <bypasslist
        <add address="[a-z]+\.contoso\.com" />
      </bypasslist>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Although that [doesn't seem to work with authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311746/how-to-pass-credentials-in-defaultproxy-config-setting).