# How can I read the values of the defaultProxy settings from the system.net section in a web.config?

Tags: c#, proxy, web-config

I am trying to read the values of my default proxy settings at runtime, but I can't seem to find any way of doing so.  There are plenty of related answers on how to **set** a default proxy (e.g. [How to pass credentials in defaultProxy config setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311746/how-to-pass-credentials-in-defaultproxy-config-setting)), but I'm looking for how to **read** these settings.

The reason behind this is that we sometimes turn on the proxy so we can capture traffic on the server with Fiddler, and I want to create a fail-safe that notifies me if someone has accidentally left it in this state after closing Fiddler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up reading the values through the Configuration manager rather than through System.Net.WebProxy:

```
var proxy = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/defaultProxy") as System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySection  
if (proxy != null) { /* Check Values Here */ }
```

The DefalutProxySection class has properties for "Enabled" and "Proxy.ProxyAddress" that met my needs.

Answer (score 0):

With the following web.config section:

```
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
  <proxy usesystemdefault="False" proxyaddress="http://1.1.1.1" bypassonlocal="True" />
</defaultProxy>
```

The following code returns the proxy information from web config:

```
Uri proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(new System.Uri("http://www.google.com"));
```

Comment: Thanks, Jamie.  This almost did what I needed.  All the properties of the proxy seem to be available, but it wasn't clear how to check if the proxy is enabled or not.  Also, wouldn't this method initiate a web request to the URI?